# React functional component setState not updating the state

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I am building a Pomodoro clock as described in Free Code Camp curriculum [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/front-end-libraries/front-end-libraries-projects/build-a-pomodoro-clock).

Code is available [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-sun-5uzg0).

In `Timer` component, `isSessionMode` state which holds a `boolean` value is toggled conditionally in `startTimer` method (line: 40) as below.

```
setIsSessionMode((prev) => !prev);
```

But the state doesn't seem to be updated because the logger in `useEffect` hook doesn't print the state (line: 19) after `setIsSessionMode()` is called as below.

```
useEffect(() => {
      console.log(isSessionMode)
      if (isFirstRun.current) {
        isFirstRun.current = false;
        return;
      }
      audioRef.current.play();
    }, [isSessionMode, audioRef]);
```

And also the state dependent log in `return` statement on line: 74 doesn't print value as expected according to the updated state as below.

```
{isSessionMode ? "Session" : "Break"}
```

Why `isSessionMode` is not getting updated?

Also, it seems that when updating the `isSessionMode` state with `setSessionMode()`, a warning is thrown as follows:

```
Warning: Cannot update a component (`Timer`) while rendering a different component (`App`).
```

I searched around the web regarding it a bit but is unable to follow.

Comment: I just commented out the line for `// if (prevTimerLength > 0) return prevTimerLength - 1;`
and the `useEffect` seems to be working for me. https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-cdn-yr2o8?file=/src/components/Timer.js:1003-1067

Comment: But I need to have the state updated conditionally with the given if statement!

Answer (score 1):

You can't do a state update inside another state update.

```js
 setTimerLength((prevTimerLength) => {
        if (prevTimerLength > 0) return prevTimerLength - 1;
        setIsSessionMode((prev) => !prev);
        return -1;
      });
```

Try moving `setIsSessionMode` outside.

Comment: Could use the second argument, which is then executed after that state is updated

Comment: Is there any mention of nested setState calls being not possible in the documentation? Also, I have exactly same app built same way in codepen which works totally fine -https://codepen.io/abhi747/pen/eYZNbpb

Comment: @KennyJohnJacob, second argument is not possible for setState method in useState hook.

Comment: Oh yes! my bad!!